# How to use IFS more concisely- excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs

I'm trying to search many cells in the B column for the number 1. When the 1 is found, I want to display the value in the A column of the row in which the 1 was found. I am very new to excel formulas, but this is what I tried:

=IFS('8&Under'!B3=1,'8&Under'!A3,'8&Under'!B4=1,'8&Under'!A4,'8&Under'!B5=1,'8&Under'!A5,'8&Under'!B6=1,'8&Under'!A6,'8&Under'!B7=1,'8&Under'!A7,'8&Under'!B8=1,'8&Under'!A8,'8&Under'!B9=1,'8&Under'!A9,'8&Under'!B10=1,'8&Under'!A10,'8&Under'!B11=1,'8&Under'!A11)

It works, but is horribly long, and I will need to recreate it many times for the whole application to work out.

Thanks.

Comment: Post few sample data with your post. `XLOOKUP()` may simplify your formula.

Comment: If you only want to "find" those rows, then a conditional format may be one method. However, if you need the count then countif() would work.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use FILTER to dynamically show a range based on matching criteria

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filter-function-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759

Answer (score 0):

you can use either function

Normal function =IF(B2=1,"Found the number 1","")

Range function =IF(B2:B27=1,"Found the number 1","")

[image: Here is the example]

Comment: Before using any formulas, the A and B column will both be full of values. Instead of returning "Found the number 1" I want to return a value already listed in the A column to the left of the 1 that was found. This can be returned in a completely different cell, let's say D10. So when the formula finds 1 in the B column, it should return the value in the cell directly to the left of the cell containing the 1 to D10.

Comment: @ASaw you need to add more information. you are just confusing. what i gave you if you understand the formula, you can apply in any columns. i would request if you can share your sheet screenshot. so i can understand better